# Filter duplicate column results in two column Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i've been struggling with this query since the last 8 hours!. Below is what im trying to achieve. If you can direct me or correct me what im missing below, it would be nice.

```
  A, B, C, Date
  --------------
  1  2  3  1
  2  3  2  2
  3  2  4  3
  4  2  9  4
  5  3  4  5
  6  4  9  6
  7  4  3  7
```

My query:

> SELECT * 
>   FROM  Tbl
>   WHERE B=2 or C=2
>   GROUP BY B, C
>   order by Date DESC

This query is giving me duplicate values. What i would like to see is if B=2 or C=2, i just want only 1 row for B=2 or C=2, and also to filter out the two resulting rows to only the last row. Filtration should be done by Date column.

```
A, B, C, Date  (Query output!)
--------------
1  2  3  1
2  3  2  2
3  2  4  3
4  2  9  4
```

Expected output:

```
A, B, C, Date  (Expected output!)
--------------
1  2  3  1 (skip this row, because the next row is the latest row! and it contains 2)
2  3  2  2 (show this row for B=2 or C=2 instead of the above row)
3  2  4  3
4  2  9  4
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mvp He has `ORDER BY` in his query.

Comment: Question: In the expected output, why isn't the last row shown and no previous ones, because in it, B=2 AND the date is the largest?

Comment: @AgRizzo im expecting for the following output `2  3  2  2 |
4  2  9  4 | 3 2 4 3 | 4 2 9 4' . 2 will be the largest date for condition B=2 or C=2 after 4 and 3.

Comment: Can you tell us why every record (A =1,2,3,4) should or should not be shown?  I still do not understand why the record where A=2 should be kept?  In record A=4, B=2 AND it has the largest Date value (4).  Why isn't it the only row being shown?  The argument "skip this row because the next row is the latest row! and it contains 2" is applicable to the records where A=2 and A=3

Comment: @AgRizzo for my query 'SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE B=2 or C=2 GROUP BY B, C order by Date DESC' it gives the following rows '1 2 3 1 | 2 3 2 2 | 4 2 9 4 | 3 2 4 3 | 4 2 9 4' . I want the records to be ordered by date and also to find any two or more similar rows having duplicate values of 2. Now taking the results from the example query above, these two rows '1231' and '2322' has value B=2,C=3 and B=3,C=2. What i want is to either skip '1231' or '2322' from the result, in this case, im looking to skip the entry '1231' as its date is lower than '2322'. Thanks, if you understand what i meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
 SELECT m.* 
   FROM my_table m
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT B
             , C
             , MAX(Date) max_date
          FROM 
             ( SELECT B,C,Date FROM my_table WHERE B = 2
               UNION
               SELECT C,B,Date FROM my_table WHERE C = 2
             ) x
         GROUP 
            BY B
             , C
       ) n
      ON ((n.b=m.b AND n.c=m.c) OR (n.b=m.c AND n.c=m.b))
     AND n.max_date = m.date;
```